# Blocks in browser shows different than in cordova

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I have designed, using HTML, JS and CSS web page. In web everything absolutely how i want here is the [image: link]

but when i'm using Cordova (right now i'm using IntelXDK) it always shows on the top (not on the bottom of the page)

[image: how it shows on the device]

And, i don't know why it is. Right now code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
    <script src="js/levels.js"></script>
    <script src="js/control.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td id="cont_block">
           <div class="one_block_text" style="opacity:             1;">Лабиринт</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is css

```
body {
    margin : 0;
    text-align : center;
    font-size : 20px;
    background-color : rgb(0,0,0);
    color : rgb(255,255,255);
}
#tbl {
    /*display : table;*/
    width : 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
#cont_block {
    /*display : table-cell;*/
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    vertical-align : bottom;
    margin : 10px;
    text-align : center;
}
.one_block_text {
    padding : 10px;
    text-align : center;
    border-top : 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
    opacity : 0;
    transition : all 1s ease 0s;
}
.cont_option {
    padding : 10px;
    text-align : center;
    border-top : 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
    opacity : 0;
    transition : all 1s ease 0s;
}
.one_option {
    display : inline-block;
    padding : 5px 10px;
    border : 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
    border-radius : 5px;
    background-color : rgb(255,255,255);
    color : rgb(0,0,0);
    cursor : pointer;
    margin : 0 5px;
}
.one_option:hover {
    background-color : rgb(200,200,200);
}
.sel_option {
    background-color : rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

what should i do to make our text looks similar in web and mobile(cordova)

Thank you,
Ildar

Comment: your html and css, both are not good to generate demo to solve your issue. Please provide proper code.

Comment: i have added div inside the table